# this._parent.reorderChild is not a function when adding LayerColor to a Node

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-js

here is the cocos2d Javascript function

```
spawnGrid: function(x,y) {
    var newGrid = cc.instantiate(this.gridPrefab).getComponent('Grid');
    this.gameArea.addChild(newGrid.node);
    newGrid.init(x,y,10);

    var width = 75;
    var height = 75;
    var backgroundLayer = new cc.LayerColor(cc.Color.RED,width,height);
    this.gameArea.addChild(backgroundLayer);
    backgroundLayer.setPosition(cc.p(width * 0.5, height * 0.5));
}
```

when this line execute

```
this.gameArea.addChild(backgroundLayer);
```

the console show this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: this._parent.reorderChild is not a function
```

any idea?

Comment: Can you show us the gameArea initialization as well? Just edit the initial post

Answer (score 0):

This might be late but for future reference,

I encountered the same error while trying to draw a simple line over an empty node (960 x 460). After 30 min of frustration, I found out that there is this internal **_sgNode** that apparently does the trick. It may not be the best solution since it's an internal object and may change...

So in your case the temporary work around would be to access the original node using

```
this.gameArea._sgNode.addChild(backgroundLayer)
```

I hope this helps